# Classification of type of issue reported from text

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am interested in doing problem type classification of different problems that are reported.

For example:

> Sentence1 - The database is not responding since yesterday. We need your help on this.
>
> Sentence2 - Our network is extremely slow and i am not able to ping the server.
>
> Sentence3 - Our MSSQLServer restarted automatically.

From the sentences, we need to extract:

> Sentence1 - "Database is not responding"
>
> Sentence2 - "Network Performance"
>
> Sentence3 - "MSSQLServer Restart" etc.

In certain cases the sentences could be a little convoluted, as below:

> We're facing an issue while trying to upgrade our development installation of db.

From this, we need to understand that the problem is an UPGRADE related issue.

I am exploring this using the Stanford Dependency parser. Any suggestions would be of great help?

Comment: I believe to *extract* is the wrong word here. What you actually want to do it to *categorize* these sentences based on keywords. In this case you may be able to tackle the problem using a simple (pregenerated) list of keywords + stemming + (possibly) a bit of dependency analysis. However, if you really wanted to *extract* information from your input, you will never end up with "Performance" as in your second example - it simply does not appear in the input.

Comment: Is there a way to generate the keywords from the corpus itself? Something like a Named Entity extraction? I am getting a lot of noise words as well if i go with POS tag and use NNP in the sentence as Named Entities.